# Synchronous wget command sent via socket in python

Tags: python, sockets, wget, synchronous

I'm sending wget commands to a remote server via sockets.
Here is the *client* code:

```
import socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('192.168.1.16',12345))
s.send('wget http://url/file1')
print "file 1 OK"
s.send('wget http://url/file2')
print "file 2 OK"
s.send('wget http://url/file3')
print "file 3 OK"
s.close()
```

On the *server*, code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import subprocess
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', 12345))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    cmd = ['/bin/sh', '-c', data]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).wait()
```

I have 2 problems:

1. Instructions sent to the server are grouped. Instead of having 3 instructions, the server receives only 1 which is the concatenation of the 3 instructions
2. "File n OK" are displayed immediately while the server hasn't completed.

What modification should I do to ensure that "OK" is displayed once the download is complete for each file?
Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: why wget and not pure python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a [similar problem](http://aboutscript.com/blog/posts/300) just yesterday.  You need some way for the server to signal "I'm done."

In the client code you need it to wait for the server to be ready.  In this simple protocol any response means "I'm done."  You could do more error checking if you need it.

```
s.send('wget http://url/file1')
print "file 1 OK"
s.recv(1024) # Wait for ANY response
s.send(....
```

And the server code...

```
while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    cmd = ['/bin/sh', '-c', data]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).wait()
    conn.send('done') # Send something, ANYTHING
# EOF
```